# Copy & Paste between terminal(s) and application windows in i3

Tags: i3-wm

I have recently installed the i3 tiling window manager [1] on my Ubuntu system and I'm trying to figure out how to copy & paste between various terminal and application windows.

How can this be done?

[1] http://i3wm.org

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some terminals use `CTRL+SHIFT+C` and `CTRL+SHIFT+V` to copy and paste, while others use `CTRL+ALT+C` and `CTRL+ALT+V`, like `urxvt` (See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode#Cut_and_paste ).

For `i3wm`, try using a clipboard manager, like `clipit`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clipit
```

Add `exec --no-startup-id clipit` to `~/.i3/config` to start it automatically.

Comment: Note, `clipit` is not longer maintained. `diodon` is a common replacement

Answer (score 4):

I have just had success using the `middle mouse button` with xterm in i3 to copy from a remote terminal to firefox. Use the `middle mouse button` to copy and paste.

Comment: Yeah - it's working - select text from terminal and middle click to paste to browser

Answer (score 3):

You have had good answers above, I will just add a detail. As a default, the clipboard of each container is emptied when the container is closed. So if you copy some text from a terminal, close the terminal, and paste the text in another terminal - it will not work, because the clipboard will have been emptied in the meanwhile.

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

I installed `xfce4-terminal` which pretty much does exactly what I need.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that myself, but your copy buffer might be accessible through <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy and <kbd>v</kbd> to paste. These is also programs like `xclipboard` for capturing output of terminal commands into a clipboard. Try it out, report back!

Comment: Hi. I tried the `ctrl+shift+c` and `ctrl+shift+v` but it definitely doesn't work. Not sure about the `xclipboard` thing, sounds a bit complicated.

Comment: yah, it's more to pipe the output of a command into to get it into your clipboard

Comment: Have you tried terminator ? It's another tiling terminal which `ctrl+shift+c` works in

Comment: Terminator is kinda defying the point of i3. I tried `gnome-terminal` but it does something weird like not everything is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just got mine done by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`mouse wheel`. Then selecting from the popup that comes the option: `Select to clipboard` by moving the mouse to that option and releasing the mouse wheel. Then I went ahead and selected the text I wanted to copy in the terminal and it worked.

This was done in i3 wm